# How to redirect a page in Drupal 8 after seconds?

Tags: php, drupal-8

I used:

```
$response = new\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse('/new_page');
$response->send();
```

But here I do not have options to redirect e.g after 5s.

P.S. `header( "refresh:5;url=/new_page" );` is not a great idea, I am looking for a Drupal 8 option. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be done in the frontend, through JavaScript's [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

**Example**

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    }, 5000
);
```